# How to show X is in the co-finite topology

Tags: general-topology, definition

This might be kind of a silly question but I can't fully grasp why the set X on which the cofinite topology is defined would be contained in the Topology. 
I know that the closure of all open sets U belonging to the topology will equal X; and what if X is not a finite set ?

Comment: What is your definition of the co-finite topology?

Comment: $T_{\text cofinitnite}$ := { U $\subset$ X : X\U is finite} $\cup$ {$\emptyset$}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The complement of $X$ is the empty set, which is finite.